# Hard Error for password box on Windows Standard Embedded 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-embedded-standard

I am working on a C# application for a Windows Standard Embedded 7 platform. I have managed to create a Windows image (using Image Configuration Editor) and installed the .NET 4.5 runtime, as well as the application software. All good so far.

When I run the program, all looks well - the hardware initializes correctly and the software loads its data. However, when I go to the program's "login" dialog (an otherwise ordinary WPF dialog window that gives access to extended functionality), something odd happens. The dialog has a PasswordBox in it, and when I click (or tab focus) to that box, the software crashes with a system message box saying "Unknown Hard Error". There's no real clue as to why this happens, and it is 100% repeatable. Any ideas? Any ideas on how to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Try to search in the EventViewer for a more detailed error

Comment: Ok. It looks like it's a font problem: there's an assertion failure on

System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.get_FirstFontFamily().

Is there a special font for the password characters? Bizarre that it  would not be included in the .NET install.

Comment: And it looks very much like I am not the first to find this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ar-SA/fc2c9a54-8f66-4f1a-82be-cb40ada5fba5/systemwindowsmediafontfamily-crash-net-35-sp1-systemexecutionengineexception?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a problem with fonts (!). You need to include TrueType fonts in the Image Configuration Editor when building an IBW image for Windows Standard Embedded 7, it will NOT get picked up as a dependency in the .NET 4.x template.